# Is there a known value for the molar extinction (absorption) coefficient for amylose and amylopectin iodine complexes?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, food-chemistry, color

I am doing a colorimetry experiment with starch, and have a theoretical model based on Beer's law. To solve it, I need a known value for the molar extinction coefficients of **amylose and amylopectin iodine complexes**. Are these known values, and where can I find them?

While experimentally finding them would not be too hard, I cannot obtain pure amylose and amylopectin, so I cannot do this myself. I have done some research, but could not find many values(lack of research skills and access to scientific databases).

Any direction to papers or sources would be greatly appreciated.

*Alternatively*, a **reliable and commonly available replacement for a starch standard** would also solve my problem, if such a thing exists - this would make things much easier for me. This is a senior school experiment, so a compromise between accuracy and availability is expected.

Comment: Do you mean for the starch iodide complex or just plain starch?

Comment: Apologies, yes. I meant the starch iodine complex for amylose and amylopectin each.